# How to stack/merge geom_stars items/plots in one - in R

Tags: r, kriging, gdal-merge, stack

If I have plotted the Relative Error Maps for the Silt soil attribute for the following 4 different soil types: Cambisols, calcisols, leptosols and fluvisols that form my study case area:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_stars(data=mydata.krig["Silt.relerror"]) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="yellow", high="dark blue", limits=c(28.82262,40.85597)) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1) +
  ggtitle("Relative error (%) - Silt - Stratified Kriging
                         Cambisols") +
  theme_void() 
With this part of the code i made the following map: 
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

I have followed this procedure also for the other 2 soil types i ve got inmy sptudy area (Calcisols, Fluvisols), and i want to combine these 3 maps in one, so as to show the relative error for the soil attribute in total (so as not to have any spaces in the whole area).
Is it possible to merge these 3 ggplots in one so as to plot the holistic relative error map for clay?

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: We don't have any data and we can't see your plots, and you've not told us what the "holistic relative error" is. How do you compute it? Can you edit your question and add some more details?

Comment: @Spacedman i updated it